# Counting number of characters in a WCHAR string

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, lua

Lua has a function named `utf8.len()` which operates on a `const char *` and does the following according to the docs:

> Returns the number of UTF-8 characters in string s
>   https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5

I'm working with a customized version of Lua that interfaces with the Win32 API. Whenever I need to pass a UTF-8 string to the Win32 backend of my app, I convert it from UTF-8 to `WCHAR` using `MultiByteToWideChar()`.

Now I'm looking for a function that does *exactly* the same as Lua's `utf8.len()` function but takes a UTF-16 `WCHAR*` string instead of a UTF-8 `const char*`string. Please don't ask me about any Unicode intricacies and terminological discussions. I have already been told that the term *character* is very ambiguous when talking about Unicode but the Lua documentation uses exactly this term (see above). So what I want is a function that does exactly the same as Lua's `utf8.len()` but operates on a `WCHAR*` instead of a `const char *` ... regardless of what the Lua authors actually mean by *character*. I just want to have a function that gives me exactly the same count as `utf8.len()` but operates on a UTF-16 `WCHAR*` string generated from a UTF-8 string by `MultiByteToWideChar()`.

I hope the question is now finally sufficiently clear enough...

One last note: I'd like to avoid using external libraries like ICU if possible. Win32 API solutions are preferred.

Comment: You are asking for two different things: *Code points* and *characters*. The term *character* is very ambiguous when referring to Unicode. It could mean code point as much as grapheme cluster. Which one are you asking for?

Comment: As an aside: There is no `TSTR` type in the Windows SDK. You are probably referring to `TCHAR`, and `TCHAR` and `wcslen()` are not compatible. The former represents either a `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on the preprocessor symbols. The latter operates on `const wchar_t*` exclusively.

Comment: `TCHAR` was useful briefly when we wanted to code for both Windows 95/98/ME and Windows NT. The former did not support Unicode. But for 10 years at least this has not been relevant. You are interested in UTF-16. So use `wchar_t` and related. Don't use `TCHAR`. As for your question, you are going to have to do better at defining what you mean by a *character*. Can you give a precise definition please.

Comment: So let's try to disambiguate. Do you want to count a surrogate pair as two distinct code points or one? Do you want to count a Latin letter followed by a combining accent mark as two code points or one? And what is the intended use of this information?

Comment: @andlabs: I want to count a surrogate pair as one code point. The intended use is to find out how many characters functions like `TextOut()` will draw to the screen.

Comment: @IInspectable: Sorry, what I meant was `LPTSTR`.

Comment: `LPTSTR` is a generic text mapping. If you are interested in Unicode, use `wchar_t*`, and call `TextOutW()`. With that out of the way, are you really interested in the number of 'characters', or the size of the output?

Comment: Note that `TextOut` may not display the same number of characters as code points. There are nonspacing code points (e.g. ZWNJ) which display nothing, and nonspacing mark code points (e.g., combining ring above, variant selector) which alter an adjacent character, and languages such as Devanagari where multiple code points collaborate to make a single displayable character.

Comment: So you are interested in the count of *graphemes* — characters as considered by the end user. You can theoretically just use the `CharNext()` and `CharPrev()` functions in a loop, but those [have bugs with surrogate pairs](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/12/16/9223301.html), so you'll have to be careful if you use them for anything other than getting the length of the string. You can also use Uniscribe; [that code is a little complicated](https://github.com/andlabs/libui/blob/master/windows/graphemes.cpp).

Comment: @andreas are you aware that Unicode code points are not in a one to one relationship with graphemes?

Comment: @David: I wasn't aware that Unicode code points aren't in a one to one relationship with graphemes. However, I think that counting graphemes is basically what I want. Basically, I'm looking for an `LPTSTR` equivalent of counting the graphemes in a UTF-8 string. To count graphemes in a UTF-8 string, I can just count all non-continuation bytes, i.e. bytes that don't have `10` in the top two bits. Now I'm looking for an algorithm or a function that does the same for an `LPTSTR`.

Comment: Why do you want to work with ANSI? And your algorithm for UTF-8 is not correct. You aren't listening to what we say.

Comment: What you are describing with UTF-8 is code points again. http://unicode.org/glossary/

Comment: @David: I'm trying to listen to what you say but this turns out to be much more complicated than I expected, e.g. I don't get your reference to ANSI. What does ANSI have to do with my last reply?

Comment: @David: Also, you're once again arguing against using `TCHAR` but you aren't providing any objective evidence as to why I shouldn't use it.I already asked "What's so about bad about `TCHAR`"? in my last question but didn't receive a reply.So is this just your personal opinion or should `TCHAR` really be avoided?I'm just asking because in the Unicode introduction on MSDN there's no word on `TCHAR` being obsolete or anything.Personally,I like using `TCHAR` because it allows me to switch string datatypes by just changing compiler defines.For me this is better than hardcoding everything to `WCHAR`

Comment: You keep talking about TCHAR which allows you to target ANSI and Unicode. Do you know what TCHAR is? Those MSDN articles are 15 years old. Anyway if you want to target ANSI then I don't think I have anything to offer.

Comment: Sure, I know. It's a compiler define which switches between `WCHAR` and `CHAR` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.

Comment: So you want to support ANSI then?

Comment: I'm migrating a project from ANSI to Unicode but I'd like to keep the possibility to do ANSI compiles. No idea whether I'll ever need them, but why should I hardcode everything to `WCHAR` when there's something like `TCHAR`?

Comment: You plan to go back to Win98? Really? In that case you'd better stop using wcslen which accepts wchar_t*. Perhaps you should find some reference material and read about Unicode.

Comment: @Andreas: You seem to misunderstand, what a `TCHAR` is (or really, what ANSI/codepage encoding is). It's not just a switch between character encodings, that can represent the same alphabet. It's a switch between Unicode and something that has no place in character encodings today. ANSI encoding relies on the program to switch to the correct locale for proper interpretation. It allows for multibyte sequences just as much, but cannot encode all Unicode code points. In short: It has all the disadvantages of a MBCS without any advantages.

Comment: Plus, calling the ANSI versions of the Windows API needlessly wastes resources, as arguments are converted from/to UTF-16 on call and return, respectively. Good luck calling `CreateFileA` to open a file whose file name contains a character that cannot be represented using the thread's current locale. In all, it sounds like you really don't understand, what ANSI/codepage encoding is (also called MBCS in Microsoft's compiler).

Comment: We really have gone completely off-topic in these comments. The difference between Unicode and ANSI strings is important, but doesn't really have anything to do with the question of counting the number of code points in a string. It would be helpful if you'd explain *why* you want to do this. If it's just for outputting text, then as Raymond says, this is misleading, because a single code point does not translate to a single grapheme. There are also non-canonical encodings. Lots of headaches. You'd be better off just letting your library's text-output function (like TextOut) deal with this.

Comment: If you really need to count code points, consider using a third-party library that can do this. For example, [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). 99% of programs do not need this. It is very likely you are writing one of that 1%, given your very limited background knowledge of text encoding. (Not meant as an insult—this stuff is *hard*.) Other than visual output, which your GUI library will handle for you, you should treat strings as essentially black boxes, writing code that is completely agnostic about the encoding, representation, etc.

Comment: Completely rephrased the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the Lua `utf8` source code](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua/blob/lua-5.3/src/lutf8lib.c), `utf8.len()` just counts the number of codepoints, so (for example) combining characters would be counted separately. **`wcslen()` is the way to go, then.**

You should, however, note that if the string contains characters outside the BMP (U+10000 or higher; Emoji, for instance), `wcslen()` can't return the same thing as `utf8.len()`. This is because UTF-16 cannot represent these using a single code point; instead, it has to break the code point into two special code points that combined are called *surrogate pairs*. If you need to treat a surrogate pair as a single code point, you're going to have to write that length loop yourself.